# Debugging responsive CSS

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, ipad

I have a web page which works fine in Chrome F12 iPad simulating as well as browser resizing in Firefox.

The issue is some CSS looks messed up when viewing on real device. What is the best way to debug the CSS on a real device?

I have just bought the iPad since the issue is very critical and users have reported this several times.

Please let me know how can I fix this issue on a real iPad device?

Thank you!

Comment: how can anyone help you without see the website or any piece of code?

Comment: @freestock.tk: If you read the question carefully you would notice I just need a way how to debug the CSS on a real Ipad. This is irrespective of the code.

Comment: Question is unclear is there a problem with your CSS?

Comment: Do you happen to own an OSX device? In that case this article might prove to be of some use;
https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/02/remote-debugging-ios-safari-on-os-x-windows-and-linux/

Osing OSX and a physical usb connection one can enable safari remote-debugging (enabling you to edit css and view the DOM live on OSX while changes are visible on the iPad.)

Comment: Awesome Annihlator. Exactly the information that I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use remote debugging of safari once you connect it to a mac. Try [this](http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/).